# GitHub page not found in google

Tags: github-pages

I just set up my personal GitHub page, with GitHub Pages! Now I was wondering if this is automatically indexed by google.

I tried out what I found online and it seems it is. By the way if I do not provide the exact URL and I just type name and surname In Google search engine I do not find anything related to my page (I went through until the 6th page of results).

Do you have any clue how to deal with this issue?
I would like that people are able to find my page just typing my name and surname and without knowing the full URL a priori!

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Customizing GitHub Pages / Search engine optimization for GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/search-engine-optimization-for-github-pages/)", you will have to add [some seo tags](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag), including [one about author](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag/blob/master/docs/usage.md#usage).

That [author information](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag/blob/f19b29ea0a20c08b32e3018800da83d9da69ace5/docs/advanced-usage.md#author-information) will help Google search to point back to your site.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Just a question that I am not sure if I understood properly. As far as you know, the SEO tag I need to put into my code, should be on the top of each .html in my _layouts folder or should I configure something else? Sorry for the dumb question but I am not so practice with html!

Comment: @KimNicoli I dn't think you need to configure anything else: see https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag/blob/master/docs/installation.md, which says "
    Add the following right before `</head>` in your site's template(s): `{% seo %}`"