# Jekyll on Github blog not appearing in Google

Tags: jekyll

I know this has been asked before e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49212888/github-page-not-found-in-google).

My Jekyll on Github blog is not appearing on Google after a few weeks. I have tried adding the SEO plugin and also tried generating a Sitemap. I updated some links from elsewhere including here in Stack Overflow. Still not in Google.

My blog is [here](https://alexharv074.github.io).

My `_config.yml` is:

```
---
theme: jekyll-theme-hacker
name: Alex Harvey
author:
  twitter: alexharv074
url: https://alexharv074.github.io/
plugins:
  - jekyll-seo-tag
  - jekyll-sitemap
```

My `_layouts/_default.html` is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    {% seo %}
  </head>
</html>
```

I would greatly appreciate a suggestion on what I might have missed.

Comment: Have you tried registering your site in Google Search Console? It can help you discover indexing problems.

Comment: I had not. Hm. Ok it has not found a sitemap or anything else by the looks of it. That's very useful to know about, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitemaps and Jekyll SEO plugins won't make your site appear on Google if you don't notify in some way Google about the existence of your website or if Google can't reach it from other pages.

As you also said that you added some links to the site after a while, you will have to wait for those pages to be crawled by Google bots and let it decide if your site appears or not.

Be sure to check https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7474347?hl=en add your site to Google and request your pages to be indexed, also check that robots.txt isn't blocking Google's bot and have patience because it may take some days.

Comment: After some time my posts did appear in Google searches. I don't actually know for certain what changed.

Comment: @AlexHarvey when Google crawled this question, found your website and indexed it. Same would have happened with any other link to your website on the web.